# How to select two specific tag classes with XPath and remove all?

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, xpath

I want to use these conditions together for XPath query in PHP

```
 //*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' metadata ')]
```

and

```
*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' mw-editsection ')]
```

What should i do?

I tried something below but it is not working:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xPath->query('//*[contains(concat(\' \', normalize-space(@class), \' \'), \' metadata \') and //*contains(concat(\' \', normalize-space(@class), \' \'), \' mw-editsection \ ]');
if($nodes->item(0)) {$nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));}
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

and there are more than one `metadata` and `mw-editsection` classes on my dom structure, I want to remove **all** metadata and mw-editsection classes

like

```
<body>
...

<div class="metadata"> abc </div>
<div class="mw-editsection"> xyz </div> 
...
<div class="metadata"> 123 </div>
<div class="metadata"> 456 </div>
<div class="metadata"> 789 </div>
<div class="mw-editsection"> abc </div> 
...
</body>
```

I want to remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath uses logical `and`, but your example suggests that you want logical `or`.  Using `and` would only select `div` elements such as `<div class="metadata mw-editsection"/>`, of which you show none in your example.