# Extract all <a> and <img> tags (exactly as represented in the input) from HTML 5 that contain a specific class

Tags: php, html, regex, domdocument

I need to improve some open source code. It contains a function to extract all `<a>` and `<img>` tags with a specific class from a string that represents HTML. This function uses regular expressions:

```
preg_match_all('#<img(.*)class="(.*)foo(.*)"(.*)>#Umsi', $text, $matches_img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
preg_match_all('#<a(.*)class="(.*)foo(.*)">(.*)</a>#Umsi', $text, $matches_a, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

// Build the union set from $matches_img and $matches_a
```

This works mostly, but not always. Specifically, the regular expressions can match multiple tags in a single match:

```
$text = '<a href="target1">link text 1</a><a class="foo" src="target2">link text 2</a>';

// matches whole string in a single match
preg_match_all('#<img(.*)class="(.*)foo(.*)"(.*)>#Umsi', $text, $matches_img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

##### My first approach

I tried to make the regular expression more specific:

```
// old
<a(.*)class="(.*)foo(.*)">(.*)</a>

// new
<a([^<>]*)class="(.*)edusharing_atto(.*)">([^<>]*)</a>
```

But this, too, can match substrings that contain multiple tags:

```
$text = '<img class="bar"><img class="foo" src="baz">';

// matches whole string in a single match
preg_match_all('#<img(.*)class="(.*)foo(.*)"(.*)>#Umsi', $text, $matches_img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Is there a robust way to improve on this? I could replace the second and third groups (`(.*)`) with `[^<>]*` as well, but then I'd run into trouble as soon as an images's alt or title attribute contains a pointed bracket.

##### My second approach: DOMDocument

I tried to parse the HTML with this function:

```
function getElementsByClassName($html, $className, $tagName=null) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    if ($tagName){
        $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
    } else {
        $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName("*");
    }

    $matched = [];

    for ($i=0; $i<$elements->length; $i++) {
        if ($elements->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('class')) {
            $classes = $elements->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue;
            if (str_contains($classes, $className)) {
                $matched[]=$dom->saveHTML($elements->item($i));
            }
        }
    }
    return $matched;
}
```

The problem here is that the matches I get do not correspond exactly to the input. There seems to be some encoding problem, but more important, DOMDocument was written to parse HTML 4. The function does give me me all the tags I need to extract, but there are some problems with special characters and syntax differences between HTML 4 and HTML 5. I need to get the tags *exactly* as they are contained in the input string.

Is there a robust solution to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide input you are trying to parse.

Comment: Agreed, realistically no-one can work out how to parse data they haven't seen

Comment: The strings I need to parse can contain any HTML element in any order as it is user generated. That's why I hope for a general solution. The minimal example I'm dealing with right now is `<img class="bar"><img class="foo" src="baz">` - assuming I want to extract img tags with the class "foo". However, I have already outlined a simple solution myself and pointed out the problems that this would entail...

Comment: Please provide context that shows what domdocument can't handle. Never had an issue with that. There's nothing new with `<a href="target1">link text 1</a><a class="foo" src="target2">link text 2</a>`, aside from `src="target2"` which as far as I know wouldn't do anything without possible JS involvement.

Comment: When you use DOMDocument you can't get the original HTML text. It parses it into DOM objects, just like a browser does.

Comment: It should work with HTML 4 and 5, the basic HTML syntax hasn't changed. All that changed were that new standard elements and attributes were added, but that doesn't significantly impact how DOMDocument parses it.

Comment: @user3783243 I've read warnings that DOMDocument might parse HTML 5 code into a different DOM structure in multiple places, including [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

A specific string that (due to another reason) is not handled correctly is *<img alt="äöü" class="foo" src="bar">*. The function puts out *<img alt="Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼" class="foo" src="bar">* instead. The misinterpreted umlauts indicate utf-8 is interpreted as ISO 8859-1. Replacing the second line of my function with `$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');` does not change the output, however.

Comment: 2-part dupe of : [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1604471/2943403) and [XPath to select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/721928/2943403). Semi-related: [How to select two specific tag classes with XPath and remove all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38998111/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility using `DOMDocument/DOMXPath` which I think should be pretty robust given the constraints in your question:

```php
$html = '<img alt="äöü" class="foo" src="bar"><a href="target1">link text 1</a><a class="foo" src="target2">link text 2</a><div class="foo">xxx</div>';

$contentType = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->loadHTML($contentType . $html, LIBXML_NOERROR);

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xp->query('//*[contains(@class, "foo") and (self::a or self::img)]') as $el) {
    echo $el->ownerDocument->saveHTML($el) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
<img alt="äöü" class="foo" src="bar">
<a class="foo" src="target2">link text 2</a>
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SNRue)

Comment: You might want to dynamically generate the `(self::a or self::img)` part since the asker's function passes the tag whitelist in as a parameter ...if you feel like spoonfeeding that part.

Comment: @mickmackusa given how specific the question was I didn't see the need to write a generic function to do in two steps what can be done in one. And it should be pretty easy to figure out how to generalise the code if it is required.

Comment: Thank you! At least with my sample HTML input, this works fine. `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"` is all I need to solve my umlaut problem, but `$xp->query('//*[contains(@class, "foo") and (self::a or self::img)]')` is much shorter than my approach. I’ll test this with more data.

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly support all of the modern and malformed HTML content that you might encounter, you'll need the HTML Tidy binary:
https://www.html-tidy.org/

It's a tiny, standalone binary that will correctly interpret and **standardize** all of the HTML that it encounters.

Next, you'll need a *modern* implementation of the DOMElement (and its related classes). I recommend `Masterminds\HTML5`:
https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php

This is available as a Composer package (`composer require 'masterminds/html5'`).

After that, you're off the races!

1. Use the HTML Tidy command to sanitize your HTML input
2. Use the DOMElement to traverse and manipulate the DOM

You can now use those DOM classes without any issues:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

You'll find that it can handle your exact use case very well!

Here's a class that I wrote for interfacing with the HTML Tidy binary:

```
<?php

namespace YourProject;

use Exception;

class TidyCommand
{
    private $command;

    private static $STDIN = 0;
    private static $STDOUT = 1;

    public function __construct (string $executablePath, string $settingsPath)
    {
        $settingsPathArgument = escapeshellarg($settingsPath);

        $this->command = "{$executablePath} -config {$settingsPathArgument}";
    }

    public function run (string $stdin): string
    {
        $descriptors = [
            self::$STDIN => ['pipe', 'r'],
            self::$STDOUT => ['pipe', 'w']
        ];

        echo $this->command, "\n";
        $process = proc_open($this->command, $descriptors, $pipes);

        if (!is_resource($process)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid resource: {$this->command}");
        }

        fwrite($pipes[self::$STDIN], $stdin);
        fclose($pipes[self::$STDIN]);

        $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[self::$STDOUT]);
        fclose($pipes[self::$STDOUT]);

        proc_close($process);

        return $stdout;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not interested in collecting STDERR, you could just use `shell_exec` instead.

Here's are some example Tidy settings to normalize the HTML:

```
bare: no
char-encoding: utf8
clean: no
coerce-endtags: yes
drop-proprietary-attributes: yes
hide-comments: yes
newline: LF
quiet: yes
show-errors: 0
show-info: no
show-warnings: no
strict-tags-attributes: yes
tidy-mark: no
wrap: 0
```

At this point, you should be good to go!

However, let me just say that if you succumb to temptation and attempt to write regular expressions to parse the HTML, then you are descending into a fiery pit of Hell. As you fall deeper and deeper into the W3C standards, you will eventually be consumed by them.

Save yourself! Follow the one true path to salvation: outsource this burden to third-parties, who have literally spent *decades* trying to get it all perfect for you, and will likely spend decades more as HTML continues to evolve.

Comment: Thank you! I'm concentrating on the XPath approach for now, but maybe I'll come back to your suggestions. It would be very time-consuming for my use case to integrate external libraries.